# Buttons look malformed on HTC wildfire, they look good in the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, htcsense

i've searched a lot before posting this, so excuse me if the question has been posted before.

I am currently developing an app for android, i am developing for version 1.6 and have a HTC wildfire as testing device. When i launch the app in the emulator, everything works just fine. When i lauch it on my device however, the buttons look malformed just like in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928603/android-button-looks-broken
A somewhat similair effect forms around my titlebar.

I have tried running invalidate() but no luck.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: this seems to be an auto-scaling problem. try to fiddle with multiple screens support options (sadly, using dp and 9patch isn't a panacea). http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thanks, i was too fast with asking questions i should have seen that section, adding `<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>` to the manifest seems to have solved the problem!